# Check if a UI button is pressed or an alternative option Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need a way to check if A UI button is pressed the on click event isn’t really helpful because the Input method (called etch time its the player’s turn) has to return a value back to the main function while loop will completely stop the game and the input should only be accepted when it’s the players turn (when players turn Method is waiting for input) , for these reasons the Unity Event Trigger doesn’t seem like a useable option .all I need is a way to check the state of the button .

**Note: that im useing Start() method of an object as my Main method
if there should be any problems with that let me know**

**ALSO NOTE : I’m transferring the game to Unity so I want to change the input+output methods with minimal changes to the code**

```
 //TurnInput is an array of bools tracking witch buttons are being pressed 
 //(9 buttons)
 private  Block[] PlayerTurn(Block[] grid )
{
    TurnNotDone = false;
    while (!TurnNotDone)
    {
        //gets stuck unity crash
        //needs to wait until player click on one of the buttons
        //(when player click on a button is turn is over and the turn is 
        //passed to the AI)
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (TurnInput[i]) grid[i] = SetBlock("O");
    }
    return grid;
}
//trigger by event trigger on button gets an int for the button Index
public void PointerDown (int i)
{
    TurnInput[i] = true;

}
//trigger by event trigger on button gets an int for the button Index
public void PointerUp(int i)
{
    TurnInput[i] = false;
}
```

Comment: If the Unity Event Trigger is not a useable option - your code structure is messed. Can you provide a snipped of the code to clearify what you want to achieve?

Comment: An alternative is: 1. Check if mousebutton is clicked, 2. translate screen to world position 3. raycast 4. check if button was hit by the raycast.

Comment: remake the game in unity, thats my advice

Comment: @Lestat well this is really not small stuff this is absolutely not an option

Comment: Can you show the player turn method?

Comment: Ok added code with what i have tried

Comment: @joreldraw code added

Comment: @TobiasTheel  added Coe in the edit

Comment: Why do you want to do nothing until the move is finished? There is no sense in blocking rendering, physics and all other gamecomponents. You have to restructure your code arround this method. You should NEVER block the game using such a while loop.

Comment: @TobiasTheel there is 9 buttons I need to get what button the player has click on when it’s his turn and return it to the main loop , how would you do such a thing ?

Comment: @TobiasTheel this is not a game that is base on other stuff happening in the background the whole game is , User turn - AI turn until the game end etch method return the step chosen

Comment: This is a 2D game no physics or anything else just have to get User Input and Output it on the screen give the data to the AI method and Output AI step on the screen and again until game end the part im haveing problem with is getting User Input

Comment: As far as i know unity handles the MainLoop singlethreaded - that means if you block anything anywhere - everything is blocked and the game dies. So your problem is not about click events from a unity button. I guess you should try to learn the unity basics. Unity offers lots of high quality beginner tutorials.

Comment: @TobiasTheel I already know some of the basics , for this specific scenario what way would you recommend to implement the player turn method ?or finding a replacement to the player turn method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could use coroutines instead of while loop:

1. gameloop coroutine "stops" to wait user input while playerTurn is true
2. ButtonClicked event handled set playerTurn to false (add ButtonClicked method to OnClick event handler of UI button)
3. AI's turn
4. set playerTurn to true again
5. goto 1

minimal example:

```
public class MinimalExample : MonoBehaviour {

public struct Block {
    public bool isOBlock;
}

bool playerTurn;
Block[] grid;
bool[] TurnInput;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    grid = new Block[9];
    TurnInput = new bool[9];
    StartCoroutine (GameLoop());
}

// GameLoop
IEnumerator GameLoop () {
    while (true) {
        yield return new WaitWhile (() => playerTurn == true);
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            if (TurnInput[i]) grid[i] = SetBlock("O");
        }
        Debug.Log ("AI here");
        playerTurn = true;
    }
}

Block SetBlock(string s) {
    var r = new Block ();
    r.isOBlock = (s == "O");
    return r;
}

//trigger by event trigger on button gets an int for the button Index
public void ButtonClicked (int i) {
    TurnInput[i] = true;
    playerTurn = false;
}

}
```